# проверить. что массив data имеет первые элементы одинаковые с value Java

Tags: java-8

public class ArrayChar {
    private char[] data;

```
public ArrayChar(String line) {
    this.data = line.toCharArray();
}


public boolean startWith(String prefix) {
        boolean result = true;
        char[] value = prefix.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length-1;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length-1; j++)
                if (value[i] == data[j]) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
               return result;

            }




}
```

Comment: Не понятно почему не сравнивает

Answer (score 0):

Потому что независимо от результата у вас всегда true
установите false в инициализации result

Comment: Отлично. но почему то сравнивает только первый индекс, в не весь prefix

Comment: Потому что у тебя идет проверка на то входит хотя бы один элемент массива в другой или нет. Проверку сделать можно одним циклом, описаным в соседнем ответе

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте правильность расставленных '{' блоков.

**Проверка на одинаковость первых элементов может быть выполнена следующим алгоритмом:**

```
public boolean startWith(String prefix) {
    char[] value = prefix.toCharArray();
    int minLength= Math.min(value.length, data.length); // проверку осуществляем пока не достигнем 
                                                    // конца наиболее короткой строки
    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] != value[i])
        {
            return 0; // в случае нахождения несоответствия возвращаем ложь
        }
    }
    return 1; // сюда попадём только если все первые элементы в двух строках равны
 }
```

Comment: Работает, а как будет реализация  через два цикла